# How to set modprobe overlay permit_mounts_in_userns=1?

Tags: docker, debian

When trying to setup the Docker daemon to run as a non-root user (Rootless mode) on Debian, I encountered the following issue.

As described by [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#debian-gnulinux), these are the steps to follow for Debian GNU/Linux:

- Add `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` (or `/etc/sysctl.d`) and run `sudo sysctl --system`.
- To use the `overlay2` storage driver (recommended), run `sudo modprobe overlay permit_mounts_in_userns=1` (Debian-specific kernel patch, introduced in Debian 10). Add the configuration to `/etc/modprobe.d` for persistence.
- Known to work on Debian 9 and 10. overlay2 is only supported since Debian 10 and needs modprobe configuration described above.

---

From this I can make up the following command to be ran (as root user):

1. Command to configure sysctl, according to the first bullet point:

   ```
   echo "kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1" > /etc/sysctl.d/10-docker.conf \
   && sysctl --system
   ```
2. Command to configure modprobe, according to the first bullet point:

   ```
   echo "overlay permit_mounts_in_userns=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/10-docker.conf \
   && modprobe overlay permit_mounts_in_userns=1
   ```

Step one seems to work fine, however when running the command from step 2 I end up with the following error:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/10-docker.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'overlay'
```

Removing "overlay " from `/etc/modprobe.d/10-docker.conf` neither doesn't seem to solve the problem this results in the following error:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/10-docker.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'permit_mounts_in_userns=1'
```

I tried to search for some directions on how to set this configuration. However no luck, does anyone know?

Comment: I am into the same thing. I am confused where exactly to persist the command to run, because /etc/modprobe.d is a directory. Do I have to put an "overlay.conf" in the directory modprobe.d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `jelly` on freenode IRC in the `#debian` channel, the `options` keyword was missing, thus this should be the right command:

```
echo "options overlay permit_mounts_in_userns=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/10-docker.conf
```